# How to update an Spinner dynamically correctly?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-spinner

I have a spinner with a custom adapter displaying objects from a database.
When the object list changed I create a new adapter with the List and apply it on the spinner. Afterwards the first item is selected, so I tried this:

```
// 5th item selected
int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
spinner.setAdapter(newAdapter);
// 0th item selected
spinner.setSelectedItem(pos);
// 5th item is selected
```

But the GUI does still show the first item?

`spinner.invalidate()` did not help.

Is this the correct way to achieve what I want? I really could not find any information on this behavior.

Comment: have you tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: I guess the main problem was the custom spinner adapter. This works fine now

```
if (spinner.getCount() > 0) {
    pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
}
MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(context, myNewObjects);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(pos); // needed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            spinner.setSelectedItem(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried `notifydatasetChanged()` or `notifydatasetInvalidate()` method of adapter.

```
newAdapter.notifydatasetChanged()
```

Comment: Can you show me how u create mAdapter.
I mean mAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<Something>(blah blah); ??

Comment: You dont have to assign new Adapter.
U add data to the List which is used in adapter and invoke NotifyDataSetChanged() method.No new Adapter.

Comment: If I just set the new list, the UI wont be updated.

   MySpinnerAdapter aa = new MySpinnerAdapter(context, myobjects);
   spinner.setAdapter(aa);