# How to select first item of a spinner in a test

Tags: android, testing, spinner

I have a tests where I test an OnItemSelectedListener on a Spinner. It works great when testing items that is > 0. But it seems like I can't test the first item.

My current implementation that works if I select items with index > 0 looks like this.

```
final Addpointer addPointer = getActivity();

    addPointer.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            EditText address = (EditText) addPointer.findViewById(R.id.address);
            address.setText("a");
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) addPointer.findViewById(R.id.intOrHex);
            spinner.setSelection(0);
            View view = (View)  spinner.getChildAt(0);
            long id = spinner.getAdapter().getItemId(0);
            spinner.performItemClick(view, 0, id);

        }
    });
```

What do I need to do to get the test to "select" the first item?

Thanks in advance

Roland

Answer: 
1) Rahul garg about setting "animate" was the key to solve the problem.
2) But you can't trigger onSelectionChanged unless the selection actually changed (0 was initial state so I needed to set it to one before I set it back to zero.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443370/how-to-update-an-spinner-dynamically-in-android-correctly/9443400#9443400   and  in setonitemclicklistener setyour selection

Comment: @Samir It is the test that shall set the selection and it works except if I try to set it to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
spinner.setSelection(0,true);
```

The second parameter will actually animate the selection to the 0 index.

Comment: No, my OnClickListener doesn't recive a call with animate set to true

Comment: I was wrong above. But I needed to set selection to one, then setup the textfield and then set it to zero. Apparently one can't trigger the OnSelectionChanged to the same number it already is.

Answer (score 7):

**more "transparent" way:**

```
     Spinner.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION, false);**
```

*second argument is for selection animation

**this should be called after:

```
     Spinner.setAdapter(...);
```

or any kind of methods that is involving **Spinner.setSelection()** for example :

```
    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

& for OnItemSelectedListener() not to fire up

Comment: This is great! I added `Spinner.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION, false);` in `onCreate`, after referencing the spinner with Butter Knife. I also registered the spinner callback with Butter Knife. Now the callback gets called once (and only once) after activity-(re-)creation, regardless of which item is selected. This is the behaviour I need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SpinnerTest sample application in the Developer Guide. It actually sends keystrokes to the activity.