# android spinner how to set no selection value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner that takes it data from server, I want to set the first selection value like "Set City". I fill the spinner like this:

```
s_city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_city);
        ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Data.cities);
        cityAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s_city.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

I want the first selection to be `set city`, I know I can append it in the first ot `Data.cities` but I am asking if there is a standard way from android.

Comment: you can always put an extra entry in your adapter that represents "no selection", and make it the initial selected item in the Spinner.

Comment: how please ? would give me a code example

Comment: `protected static String[] cities = new String[] {""};` this is data.cities, i fill it from a server

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add "Set City" as a first spinner element.
There is an insert method in ArrayAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T, int) .You can add  your "Set City" as the first element.

Comment: Pragnani says there is a way

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra item, "Set City", to the beginning of your list and then do this:

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position == 0) {
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint("Set City");
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
```

Also don't forget to specially handle position 0 when you handle onItemSelected.

Answer (score 0):

you can set like this
Spinner.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION, false);

see this

*[How to select first item of a spinner in a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553496/how-to-select-first-item-of-a-spinner-in-a-test)*