# Spinner with sub-spinner not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner, adapter

I have two [spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), such that my second spinner changes options that it can offer according to the item selected in the first spinner. Easy?

Example: If I select 'a' in main spinner, the sub spinner should show 'a1' as option. If I select 'b' in main spinner, the sub spinner should show 'b1','b2' as options. If I select 'c' in main spinner, the sub spinner should show 'c1','c2','c3' as options.

*I use a library called [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) but that does not matter as it works just like the Android spinner.*

```
public class PostComplaint extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] problems_main = {"a","b","c"};
    String[][] problems_sub = {{"a1"},{"b1","b2"},{"c1","c2","c3"}};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_complaint);

    spinner_main = (SearchableSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_main);
    spinner_sub = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_sub);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, problems_main);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_main.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    spinner_main.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setSubSpinner(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(PostComplaint.this, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

void setSubSpinner(int i){
    String[] myArray = problems_sub[i]; //Note: problems_sub is a two dimensional array
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter_sub = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArray);
    spinnerAdapter_sub.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_sub.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter_sub);
    spinnerAdapter_sub.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Problem: Whichever item I click on the main spinner for the first time, according to that the sub spinner is selected. Then if I change the main spinner, the sub spinner is not changing.**

*The question is open for suggestions. Comment if it is not understandable.*

Comment: try with this first invalidateDataSet and then add again

Comment: @VivekMishra You mean `spinner_sub.invalidateDataSet()` ?

Comment: yes like that as data in it is according to old spinner. you first remove that data and then add new one

Comment: @VivekMishra There is not such method as `invalidateDataSet()`. I tried `spinner_sub.invalidate();` as the fist line in method `setSubSpinner()`. No help yet.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443370/how-to-update-an-spinner-dynamically-in-android-correctly

Comment: For a normal android spinner class, your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: @ObscureGeek I didn't think of that. I definitely will try with the normal spinners.

Comment: However, with the SearchableSpinner class, there seems to be something wrong. Unless you have a mandatory requirement to use that class, I would suggest to use the default one only.

Comment: @ObscureGeek Anything wrong that you could describe?

Comment: Upon selecting an item in the main spinner it is loading the correct data set in the sub spinner but upon sub spinner click it is displaying old or stale data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because of the following function in the SearchableSpinner Class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getAdapter();

        if (null != adapter) {

            if (_items.size() == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    _items.add(adapter.getItem(i));
                }
            }
            SearchableListDialog searchableListDialog = SearchableListDialog.newInstance
                    (_items);
            searchableListDialog.setOnSearchableItemClickListener(this);
            searchableListDialog.show(((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The condition `if(_items.size() == 0)` becomes true only the first time you click on the sub spinner and hence it gets initialized correctly and you will see correct values. However, once you have clicked on the sub spinner, `_item.size()` will never be zero and thus, the updated sub spinner values will never be rendered.

I suggest you use the default Android Spinner or fork the repository and fix the error and use the same.

**EDIT**

You can try using this class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableListDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomSearchableSpinner extends Spinner implements View.OnTouchListener,
    SearchableListDialog.SearchableItem {

private Context _context;
private List _items;
private boolean isDataSetChanged;

public CustomSearchableSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this._context = context;
    this.isDataSetChanged = true;
    init();
}

public CustomSearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this._context = context;
    this.isDataSetChanged = true;
    init();
}

public CustomSearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this._context = context;
    this.isDataSetChanged = true;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    _items = new ArrayList();
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getAdapter();

        if (null != adapter) {

            if (isDataSetChanged) {
                if(_items.size() != 0) {
                    _items = new ArrayList();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    _items.add(adapter.getItem(i));
                }
                isDataSetChanged = false;
            }
            SearchableListDialog searchableListDialog = SearchableListDialog.newInstance
                    (_items);
            searchableListDialog.setOnSearchableItemClickListener(this);
            searchableListDialog.show(((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSearchableItemClicked(Object item, int position) {
    setSelection(_items.indexOf(item));
}

public void notifyDataChanged(Boolean hasDataChanged) {
    this.isDataSetChanged = hasDataChanged;
}
}
```

Also, update your layout file and PostComplaint Class to use CustomSearchableSpinner in place of Searchable Spinner. It may not be the best approach, but it works.

**EDIT 2**

You will need to call `spinnerAdapter_sub.notifyDataChanged(true)` after you call `spinnerAdapter_sub.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: To be frank it will be difficult for me to fork and solve the issue myself, but I do want to give it a try. This will be the first time for me to fork and solve an issue. Hit me with any other hints if you can. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Oh this should work. But before I even try, you deserve a huge thanks. 21 hours to give away the bounty. Patience.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey, if I understood your code correctly, didnt you miss the else part of `if(isDataSetChanged)`? Where you need to place the `for` loop to add the contents?

Comment: Nope, in that case it will display the previously created list and not populate _items again. However, I forgot to mention something. I have updated my answer again.